# ¿Cómo seleccionar varios elementos con una misma clase desde JavaScript? Y además meterle animaciones

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un problema y es que he creado unas cards a las las cuales le he agregado unas animaciones al hacer scroll pero solo funciona en una de ellas ya que tienen la misma clase en html

```
    let card = document.querySelector(".card")
    let cardPosition = card.getBoundingClientRect().top;
let tamanoDepantalla = window.innerHeight*0.70;
if (cardPosition < tamanoDepantalla) card.style.animation =  "card-animation 3s "; 

}      ) `
```

Answer (score 0):

el querySelector solo toma el primer elemento con la clase que le pasas, debrias usar el querySelectorAll y recorrer el arreglo, algo asi:

```
let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card")
for (const card in cards) {
  let cardPosition = card.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let tamanoDepantalla = window.innerHeight*0.70;
  if (cardPosition < tamanoDepantalla) card.style.animation =  "card-animation 3s ";
```

y todo eso dentro de un EventListener